# replacing status command of upstart in ubuntu 16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma

While implementing `puma`, I have updated ubuntu version from 14.04 to 16.04.

Prior service was based on upstart, basically `workers` and `sidekiq` started with upstart. However, the problem occurs when I try to deploy actual code.

During the deployment, prior code checked status of workers via code like below.

```
if capture('status workers') =~ /start/
```

I have not installed `upstart` in ubuntu 16.04 thereby deploy failed at this point. Is there anyway that I can substitute such command driven from `upstart` in ubuntu 16.04?

Also `Kernel.capture` which is shown above is also deprecated code. Is there any substitutions for these, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `systemd` utils in Ubuntu 16.04:

- `sudo systemctl status puma.socket puma.service` for Puma - see the [Puma systemd page](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md)
- `sudo systemctl status sidekiq` for Sidekiq - see [Sidekiq's systemd service file](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/systemd/sidekiq.service)

Instead of using Kernel.capture, use Ruby Open3 methods - there's a [good article on them](http://blog.honeybadger.io/capturing-stdout-stderr-from-shell-commands-via-ruby/).